# stack management in CLR

Tags: clr

I understand the basic concept of stack and heap but great if any1 can solve following confusions:

1. Is there a single stack for entire application process or for each thread starting in a project a new stack is created?
2. Is there a single Heap for entire application process or for each thread starting in a project a new stack is created?
3. If Stack are created for each thread, then how process manage sequential flow of threads (and hence stacks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is a separate stack for every thread. This is true not only for CLR, and not only for Windows, but pretty much for every OS or platform out there.
2. There is single heap for every Application Domain. A single process may run several app domains at once. A single app domain may run several threads.
   To be more precise, there are usually two heaps per domain: one regular and one for really large objects (like, say, a 64K array).
3. I don't understand what you mean by "sequential flow of threads".

Comment: Thanks for clearing first 2 questions... With 3rd I meant:
Lets say, When my project started, a Main Thread would have started (with its  own stack)

If I just simply call another method in same class will it be on a new thread or will be using the same master thread?
If it will be on a new Thread, then how my Main thread manage sequence? Will Main thread stack contain a pointer to this new thread stack so that upon completion of second thread it can resume.. something like that?

Comment: Calling another method does not create a new thread. New threads have to be created explicitly. Your questions suggest that you are not quite familiar with the idea of threads. Try to read something on the subject first. I couldn't find a good article right away, but this one seems credible enough: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/multithreadingintro10062005000439am/multithreadingintro.aspx

Comment: THanks.. Are my following points correct?
1. When an application starts, at least one thread is definitely created

2. Application is here analogous to Process

3. Each Thread has its own stack

4. Process can have multiple thread

5. Unless explicitly created, program runs in a single thread. Hence calling methods in sequential mode doesn’t create a new thread

6. New Threads can be created explicitly and each Thread will have its own stack but heap is shared among a processe's threads

Comment: The last point is only partially correct. If you're talking about CLR, there will be a new heap if you create another application domain.

Answer (score 4):

One stack for each thread, all threads share the same heaps.

There is no 'sequential flow' of threads.  A thread is an operating system object that stores a copy of the processor state.  The processor state includes the register values.  One of them is ESP, the stack pointer.  Another really important one is EIP, the instruction pointer.  When the operating system switches between threads, it stores the processor state in the current thread object and reloads the state from the thread object for the thread that was selected to run next.  The processor now simply continues executing where it left off previously.

Getting a thread started is perhaps now easy to understand as well.  The operating system allocates a megabyte of memory for the stack.  And initializes the ESP register value to point to that memory.  And sets the value of the EIP register to the address of the method where the thread should start executing.  The value of the ThreadStart delegate in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread must have it's own stack, that's where local variables and parameters are held, and the return addresses of the previous functions.

Comment: With Previous functions you mean Thread+Stack of function which invoked this method.. and on completion it will automatically return to caller's thread stack walk?

Comment: Function which invoked this method.